# sencha framework problem after update 2.2 to 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, extjs

After ExtJS update 2.2 to 3.3.1 i have got a problem i can't solve.

I think its a TreePanel that is created. But there is no childNodes in "this"-object so:

> ERROR: cs is null

```
renderChildren : function(suppressEvent){
    if(suppressEvent !== false){
        this.fireEvent('beforechildrenrendered', this);
    }
    var cs = this.childNodes;
    for(var i = 0, len = cs.length; i < len; i++){
        cs[i].render(true);
    }
    this.childrenRendered = true;
},
```

I can't figure out what is causing this problem, can't find who is calling this command.

Comment: care to provide your TreePanel code?

Comment: the problem is that my solution is pretty complicated, thats why i am not sure where its comming from.

Comment: The problem is not in ExtJS itself (ie. the code you posted here) but somewhere in your own code. How are you adding nodes to your tree? And how did you define your TreePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in by looking in stack:

```
MapPanel.js (rad 77)
```

Code:

```
        var toc = new MyPanel.Toc( {
            map :map,
            border :false
        });
        tocPanel.add(toc);
        //toc.update(); //When i comment out these it works. 
        //tocPanel.doLayout();
```

> *"A TreePanel must have a root node before it is rendered."* [class=Ext.tree.TreePanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.tree.TreePanel)

Could it be this?

Answer (score 0):

`this` is probably `window`. Check that context (`this`) is set properly when the function is called (or event attached).

Comment: Not `Ext.Window` but browser's `window` object. Put `alert(this === window)` before `var cs = ...` and see what happens.